# What is the terminology used to describe control without measurement?

Tags: control

I am currently writing a paper on information theory. In the paper, I will be comparing feedback control ( with observations of the environment, of course) and control without observations.

My question is that what is the established technical terms for control without observation.

In my paper, the presence or absence of observation is an important point of discussion. Therefore, I would like to use a technical term that emphasizes the absence of observation.

I searched Google scholar with the following query:

- "control without measurement": 69 papers
- "control without
  observation": 5 papers
- "measurement-free control": 10 papers
  "observation-free control": 0 paper
- "unobserved control": 198 papers
- "unmeasured control": 107 papers

I do not feel that those terms is appropriate.

Comment: How about term such as, non-feedback control or open-loop control?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In control theory, we refer to this as "open-loop control", which emphasizes the lack of a feedback loop.

The [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-loop_controller) has several examples of open-loop control.